# Stack level too deep (System Stack Error)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nginx, passenger

I have a message architecture where the messages are itself nested for one level. Each message (parent) can have many children and each message (children) belongs to parent.

The `parent_id` attributes identifies if a message is a parent/child and also whose child it is.

Please find below my model and the corresponding associations.

```
Class AbstractMessage

  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'AbstractMessage', inverse_of: :children    

  scope :with_a_parent, where("parent_id IS NOT NULL")

  has_many :children, class_name: 'AbstractMessage', foreign_key: :parent_id, 
  include: [:children],
  conditions: "id IN (#{AbstractMessage.with_a_parent.select(:id).to_sql})",
  inverse_of: :parent

end
```

Here in this case, I am facing an infinite recursion loop with the following query.

```
AbstractMessage.where(id: message_root_ids).includes(:children).index_by(&:id)
```

The strange part is that `this issue happens only when it is being called via web server (passenger/nginx)`. The same query when fired from console returns the proper results.

Any help on why this issue occurs. Also why it happens only through web server.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The way your application work will never be affected whether your running it through the server or not. If you think so, that means that the error actually sits somewhere else. This is usually the case for "Stack level too deep" error, stacktrace cannot be that trusted.

Comment: Wild guess here - is there a chance that you have a message in your database which is its own descendant?

Comment: @BroiSatse Thanks for suggestions. I checked and confirmed that there are no recursive descendants. Is there a way to increase the size of the stack ? I did a quick search for found that `ulimit` is one way to increase the stack size.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Yes. I looked at logs but no help. There are no proper traces in the logs.

Comment: The size of the stack is not the problem:  if something is stuck in an infinite loop, which is almost always what causes a "stack level too deep" problem, then making the stack deeper will just mean the problem takes a fraction of a second longer to manifest itself.

Comment: @SabarishSankar - Do you really need that condition in your query? Try removing include part of the association - I know it might cause stronger N+1 issue, I just want to confirm if that's the issue or not. As MaxWilliams already said, increasing size of the stack won't help you here as this seems like infinite recursion issue.

Comment: @MaxWilliams The issue actually happens in the production server. When I tried to dump the same production database in my local, I could not reproduce the issue. The pages just renders fine. That is the reason I suspect the stack size could be the problem.